# Find largest square in matrix that can move from one corner to the other

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matrix

You have a matrix of 0 and 1 for example:

```
1 1 1 0
1 1 1 0
1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1
1 0 1 1
```

A square is placed at position (0,0), find the size of the largest square of all 1s that be move from the upper left corner to the lower right corner. The square can only move down and to the right and only over elements which are 1.

In this example the size of the largest square is 2. The indexes of elements in the square are (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1).

I'm not sure how to solve this problem. I think first, you need to find the all the squares in the upper left corner and all squares in lower right corner. If the move is possible, then there must be squares in these 2 positions that are the same size. Then only attempt to move squares in the left corner that are equal in size to square in right corner. But I'm not sure how to go about finding the squares and checking if they can be moved.

Comment: It looks like a search problem - consider all possible squares you can form at (0,0) and, for each, search for a path to the opposite corner. The search can be optimized using dynamic programming. Have a can-reach-the-bottom-right-from-here table. At each location, if a square can be placed there *and* one of the locations one step right or down is already flagged in the table, flag this cell too. If you start with the largest possible square (4,4) and count down each time one is disproven, the first one you find is the solution you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic programming.

1. Let's assume that `max_size(i, j)` is the size of the largest square that can stay in a `(i, j)` cell(possibly 0)(stays in means that its top left corner is located in this cell). We can compute this value in a naive way(by iteratively increasing the size of the square and checking that it does not touch any `0`). If a naive solution is not feasible, we can use binary search over the answer and prefix sums to get an `O(log n)` time per cell.
2. Let's say that `f(i, j)` is the largest square that can reach the `(i, j)` cell. The base case: `f(0, 0) = max_size(0, 0)`(we can always reach the the top left corner). For the other cells, it can be computed in the following way(I omit corner cases here):

   ```
   for i <- 0 ... n - 1:
       for j <- 0 ... m - 1:
           f(i, j) = min(max_size(i, j), max(f(i - 1, j), f(i, j - 1)))
   ```
3. The answer is the largest `f(i, j)` such that `i + f(i, j) - 1 = n - 1` and `j + f(i, j) - 1 = m - 1`.

The time complexity is `O(n * m * log(min(n, m)))`.

Comment: what do you mean by "max_size(i, j) is the size of the largest square that can stay in a (i, j)"?  what do you mean by "can stay in"?  Has a top left corner at?  Has a lower right corner at?  Centered at?  or contains?  For example, consider the matrix given in the original post, what is max_size(4,3)?

Comment: @thang  I mean that it has the  top left corner in this cell.

Answer (score 0):

Your first step is right: find the largest square that fits into both the lower right and the upper left.

Then, start with a square of that size in the upper left.  Try the paths to the lower right breadth-first.  After each step, you check whether the square still fits, otherwise reduce its size.  You will then often arrive at a given place from two directions (from above and from the left).  Continue from there with the bigger size (this unification step is why you should go breadth-first, this is also called "dynamic programming").

In your example, you start with an array of size 2 at `(0 0)`, but let's say that you start with size 3 for demonstration purposes.  So, layer 0 is a single square of size 3 at `(0 0)`.  Moving down is no problem, but moving to the right steps on some zeroes, so you have to reduce the size.  Layer 1 is thus a list of two squares: one of size 3 at `(1 0)` and one of size 2 at `(0 1)`.  Next layer: move right from `(0 1)`, need to reduce to size 1 at `(0 2)`; move down from `(0 1)` as well as right from `(1 0)`, both arrive at `(1 1)`, from above with size 2, from left needs to reduce to size 2, so size 2; move down from `(1 0)`, reduce to size 2.  So, Layer 2 is a list of three squares: one of size 2 at `(2 0)`, one of size 2 at `(1 1)`, and one of size 1 at `(0 2)`.  I think this suffices as a demonstration.

You have reached a solution when you complete a layer that contains a square that touches the lower right.  You can tell that there is no solution when all your squares are size 0.

Answer (score 0):

## Brute force solution

If your matrix has size `N x M`, every path of a square of size `S x S` from top left to bottom right is `N + M - 2S` 'steps' (movements to the right or left) long, where `N - S` steps will go downwards and `M - S` steps rightwards. So if we disregard the values on the matrix, there will be `(N + M - 2S) choose (N - S)` possible paths.

So if the matrix isn't too large, it might be feasible to just try all these paths for a given square size `S` and test them for compliance with the square placement rules (whether in each step, the square only covers `1`s and no `0`s.)

Do this for each `S` from `1` to `min(N,M)`, and keep track of the values of `S` for which you can find at least one valid path.

Then, just take the maximum of these `S` values and you've got the wanted result.

So brute-forcing will (eventually) give you the correct value.

## Optimizations

Off course, this isn't as efficient as could be, which will lead to enormous runtimes for large matrices. But we can improve step by step, by looking into what steps are unneccesary.

### One valid path for a given square size suffices

If you've found a valid path for a given square size `S`, you don't have to look for more paths for the same square size and can skip to testing other, yet untested square sizes.

### One invalid step kills the whole path

If any step of a path leads to an invalid placement, you don't have to check the other steps. You already know you can't use the whole path.

### Don't do double work

Each of the `(N-S) * (M-S)` possible placements of a square with given size `S` will be part of several paths. Instead of checking each placement's validity for each path it is part of, do it just once for each placement and store the result in a `(N-S) x (M-S)` matrix.

### Bigger won't fit better

If you've tested all paths for a given square size `S`, and none of them was valid, you don't have to test larger `S` at all, as you know there won't be valid paths for them.

### Smaller won't fit worse

If you've found a path for a given square size `S`, you can be sure that all smaller square sizes will have at least one valid path, too, so you don't have to test them. (You wouldn't have to, anyway, as you're looking for the maximum `S` with at least one valid path.)

### Bisection?

Combining the two realizations above, you'll come to the conclusion that it won't be optimal to test sizes `S` in order, be it increasing or decreasing. Rather, you could start somewhere in-between and —depending on the result for that `S`— rule out all smaller or all larger values for `S`. Whether it is optimal to start exactly in the middle (at `min(N,M) / 2`), I'm not sure, though, as the number of paths to search for a given `S` (remember the binomial coefficient formula in the "Brute force" section above) depends on the size of `S`.

### Parallelization

Almost every level of the brute force algorithm has several steps that are independent of each other and could be executed in parallel.

### More?

I'm sure even with all of the above implemented, there's still room for more optimization, even if I can't think of any right now.